# Rails 3 basic validation not working with :prompt or :include_blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model, controller

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, user_all_select_options, :include_blank => '--Select a name-----' %>
```

It displays a list of users with `--Select a name-----` at the top. When a user doesn't select a name from the list and leaves `--Select a name-----` selected I get errors because the user_id is blank.

For reference the helper method code looks like this:

```
def user_all_select_options
  User.all.map{ |user| [user.name, user.id] }
end
```

My model is as follows:

```
class Parcel < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :parcel, :received_at, :received_by, :chilled, :courier, :location, :passed_to, :user_id, :user, :content, :localip

  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  belongs_to :user

end
```

For some reason the validation doesn't appear to be running, however if I select a user from the drop down and add a validation for an other field input the application correctly shows the user a message stating which field is incorrectly empty.

Interestingly if I leave the select drop down as `--Select a name-----` and keep the additional validation, an exception is thrown. It doesn't prompt for the missing fields it just errors.

Here is the record during an error (this record was from when I had a validates presence check on the location field:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wM4KPtoswp3xdv8uU4UasdadNsZi9yFZmk=", "parcel"=>{"user_id"=>"", "received_by"=>"dan", "content"=>"", "chilled"=>"0", "courier"=>"", "location"=>"", "passed_to"=>"", "received_at(3i)"=>"9", "received_at(2i)"=>"2", "received_at(1i)"=>"2013", "received_at(4i)"=>"22", "received_at(5i)"=>"59"}, "commit"=>"Receive this Parcel", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"parcels"}
```

Where should I start looking? The errors that show are when the controller does an unless check against the user.

The parcel controller create method looks like this:

```
  def create
    @parcel = Parcel.new(params[:parcel])
    @parcel.localip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
    @parcel.received_by = @parcel.received_by.upcase

    unless @parcel.user.mobilenumber.blank?
      UserMailer.parcel_notification(@parcel).deliver
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @parcel.save
        format.html { redirect_to @parcel, notice: 'Parcel was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @parcel, status: :created, location: @parcel }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @parcel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: are you using the bang methods? (`save!` or `create!`).  these methods return an exception when validation fails.

Comment: No, I've added the create method of the controller to my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why you're getting an exception when you don't select a user is this line

```
unless @parcel.user.mobilenumber.blank?
```

since the `user_id` is not set, `@parcel.user` is `nil` which causes the exception.
I suggest you move that inside the `@parcel.save` block.

```
def create
  @parcel = Parcel.new(params[:parcel])
  @parcel.localip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  @parcel.received_by = @parcel.received_by.upcase

  respond_to do |format|
    if @parcel.save
      unless @parcel.user.mobilenumber.blank?
        UserMailer.parcel_notification(@parcel).deliver
      end

      format.html { redirect_to @parcel, notice: 'Parcel was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @parcel, status: :created, location: @parcel }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @parcel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```